# forgot password event for frontend

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, event-observer, frontend, customer-account

I am using magento1.7.0.2 , want to perform some operation while user submit request for forgot password from frontend using event observer.

i tried customer_save_after is a event for adminhtml not for frontend.

any help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play around with events:

To run your observer after reset password action

```
controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_forgotpassword
```

and in your observer add checking if email is sent

```
$email = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
if ($email) {
    //here place your code to notify customer
}
```

Comment: I have tried using above events. my code is here..its not calling the observer method.<controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_resetpassword>
   <observers>
    <send_forgetpassword_sms>
     <class>Test_Tested_Model_Observer</class>
     <method>ForgetPasswordAlerts</method>
    </send_forgetpassword_sms>
   </observers>
  </controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_resetpassword>

Comment: Instead of `resetpassword` try to use `forgotpassword`. See answer I updated it.

Comment: Thanks.i tried but it is calling method when i click on forgot password link. i want after entering email id need customer data to alert them with new password. I have placed in frontend area.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Use event`controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_forgotpasswordpost`
instead of `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_forgotpassword`